# How to swap object order inside an array by a provided property

Tags: javascript

I have an array with objects: `let array = [{value:"name", order: 1}, {value:"age", order:2}, {value: "other", order:3}]`

I want to change their order property so that the order of name becomes 2, the order of other 3 and the order of age 1. The array should change to:

```
let array = [{value:"age", order: 1}, {value:"name", order:2}, {value: "other", order:3}]
```

I know I can do this easily by just swapping their indexes but I was wondering if I can somehow swap their order values anyway without manually changing them, I tried this but it does not work:

```js
let array = [{value:"name", order: 1}, {value:"age", order:2}, {value: "other", order:3}]

let name = array.find(obj => obj.value === "name");
let age = array.find(obj => obj.value === "age");
if (name) { 
  var temp = age
  name = age
  age = temp

}
array.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order); 
console.log(array)
```

So how can I achieve this by using their order property?

Comment: Could you please add to your question an example of the expected output?

Comment: @Calvin Nunes done

Comment: ok, so, you want to sort the array alphabetically using the `value` property, then after it being sorted, set yhe `order` equals to its current index?

Comment: Why do you need the `order` property at all? You can easily determine it with `array.indexOf(obj) + 1` ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the object `order` property needs to be updated as below:

```js
let array = [{value:"name", order: 1}, {value:"age", order:2}, {value: "other", order:3}]

let nameObj = array.find(obj => obj.value === "name");
let ageObj = array.find(obj => obj.value === "age");
if (nameObj && ageObj ) { 
  var temp = ageObj.order
  ageObj.order = nameObj.order
  nameObj.order = temp

}
array.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order); 
console.log(array)
```